# Background Image - change default opacity value from 0.5 to 1 permanently?

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view, transparency

When i add a background image then it is semi transparent. Hard to see. I need to change it to opaque by setting the corresponding slider to 1 instead of 0.5. And i have to repeat this step with every new added background image.

Is there a way to change this default value for opacity from 0.5 to 1 so that i don't have to make the background image opaque first all the time?

I already tried to save the startup file. But this value is not part of what gets saved. The BG Image panel gets created new with every new image. And i cannot find where the default value of this slider is stored. Is it even stored? Resetting to default and unset sets the slider to 0. So where does this 0.5 come from?

I am happy with any solution. Even changing c files.

[image]

Comment: Not sure why and what your intention is... Anyway, for an add-on you can use a *handler* like [this](https://gist.github.com/p2or/f07a7d51e7fd067ab1c593375a529ed8) (executes every time the file is loaded).

Comment: Thanks for the link. My intention is to set the default opacity value from 0.5 to 1. Plain and simple :)

Comment: Sorry and thanks @poor. Yes you did. It's a workaround. But i thought more about the initial value in the c or python code, so that you don't need to work around it at all. I am still curious where the 0.5 is defined. I cannot find it :'3

Comment: Set `bgpic->blend` from `ED_view3D_background_image_new()` in `view3d_edit.c` to `0`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about blenders source code.

Comment: @poor, that was what i was looking for. Many thanks :)

Comment: Wasn't there just before a few days a discussion that questions about the source code should be allowed?

Comment: @poor. The addon doesn't work by the way. Value is still at 0.5 :(

Comment: The Add-on works per file load. Setup a background image, set its opacity value for instance to .3, save it, re-open it and you'll see it works @Tiles

Comment: I think that's a great example whether such questions should be allowed or not (so please don't delete it)

Comment: I see, thanks @poor. For the offtopic if it should be allowed or not: i searched for any working solution. Not only, but also including source code modifications. The information that you need to dive into the source code to modify this default UI value is surely of help for other people.

Comment: Of course, however this doesn't matter at the moment so I want to encourage you to post your opinion [here](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2216/source-code-questions-in-2016?cb=1) instead.